# Groovy script in Jenkins - MultipleCompilationErrorsException

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, apache-poi

I have an "item" in jenkins, there are several steps:
- execute win batch
- execute groovy script

So I installed a special groovy plugin for jenkins and set a path to my groovy script. This script ist *working fine* in groovy console and in cmd.  But exactly in Jenkins, I'm getting errors:

```
$ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-3.0.0\bin\groovy.exe" -cp C:\Users\lokadm\.groovy\utils C:\Folder\myscript.groovy

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
file:/C:/Users/lokadm/.groovy/utils/ExcelUtils.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet

@ line 6, column 1.
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet
```

Groovy script settings:
[image]

I assume the problem is connected with Apache Poi. While executing main script, I'm also calling another one - ExcelUtils.groovy. In this script all poi classed were imported. Start of the ExcelUtils.groovy:

```
import java.io.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
```

I tried also to add poi.jars into groovy setting classpath, but seems it doesn't help. [image]

What to do?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: there is no poi jars in current classpath.

Comment: @daggett Well, then how can i make it? I tried adding jars to "classpath" field in jenkins step, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please edit question and add more information about exactly one case of failure. If you are talking about jenkins or jenkins-pipeline - show the configuration of step and directory content where poi files located.

Comment: Added more information, hope that's helps.

Comment: do you have in full stacktrace any Caused by ? there could be a reason of problem.

Comment: I'm using see only Console Output, the errors from which I've posted already.

Comment: It should work. all jars must be specified separately (not just folder). try to run your script from command line like `groovy -cp "path/to\classes;path/to/jars/name1.jar;path/to/jars/name2.jar;" path/to/script.groovy`. if it works fine - reproduce the same params in jenkins.

Comment: It worked! I've added all jars (because I have more than 2) into settings (groovy "classpath" is filled with full paths to all jars and to special folder with another scripts) and now it's working correctly.
Thanks a lot, @daggett!